# How to calculate average number of entries for grouped data

Tags: python, pandas

How can I calculate the **average number** of entries having `GRADE` equal to `4` and `5` for each group `<Day,Hour>`? For example, these should be average values fpr Day 1 and Hour 7 over months, for Day 1 and Hour 8 over months, etc.

```
MONTH DAY  HOUR  GRADE
1     1    7     4
1     1    7     4
1     1    7     4
1     1    7     4
1     1    8     5
1     1    8     4
2     1    7     5
2     1    7     5
2     1    7     4
2     1    7     4
2     1    8     5
2     1    8     5
```

If I do this, it counts all entries for each group.

```
grouped = df.groupby(['DAY','HOUR'], as_index=0)['GRADE'].agg(['count'])
```

However I need the output in the following format (the average values of `GRADE_4` and `GRADE_5` are invented):

```
DAY  HOUR  GRADE_4  GRADE_5
1    7     25       41
1    8     37       42
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to achieve. Are you trying to *count* the number of entries with `GRADE == 4`? What do you mean "the average values of `GRADE_4` and `GRADE_5` " ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- group over `['MONTH', 'DAY', 'HOUR', 'GRADE']` to get number of grades over all dimensions.
- group over `['DAY', 'HOUR', 'GRADE']` to get mean per month.

---

```
df.groupby(['MONTH', 'DAY', 'HOUR', 'GRADE']).size() \
    .groupby(level=['DAY', 'HOUR', 'GRADE']).mean().unstack() \
    .rename_axis([None], 1).rename(columns='GRADE_{}'.format) \
    .reset_index()

   DAY  HOUR  GRADE_4  GRADE_5
0    1     7      3.0      2.0
1    1     8      1.0      1.5
```

Comment: One small question: What if I just wanted to know the average grade over months grouped by day and hour (i.e. to get `GRADE` instead of `GRADE_4` and `GRADE_5`).

Comment: @Dinosaurius that should be `df.groupby(['DAY', 'HOUR']).GRADE.mean()`

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this, this gives the total count of `Grade4` and `Grade5` grouped by `Day` and `Hour`. If you need average count per month, you can divide the Grades columns by the number of unique months:

```
df.GRADE = "GRADE_" + df.GRADE.astype(str)

(df.groupby(["DAY", "HOUR", "GRADE"]).MONTH.count()
   .rename_axis(("DAY", "HOUR", ""))
   .unstack(level=2).reset_index())
```

[image]